# Java ASM visitMethod access 4161 meaning

Tags: java, jar, java-bytecode-asm

I have the following inheritance structure:
[image]

`SomeModel` implements `Entity`, and `SomeModelQueryRepo` has 2 methods that return `SomeModel`: get given an Id, and get returning all `SomeModel`s in the repo.

For some reason, `visitMethod` detects another *secret* method: `get` which returns a base `Entity`.

However, that is not explicitly declared. The `access` code is a bit unusual, with a value of `4161`. I tried looking at the [opcodes](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/constant-values.html#org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ACC_SUPER), but I can't determine which combination leads to that value. What does `4161` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the [Method access and property flags](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6-200-A.1).

4161 (which is 0x1041) corresponds to this combination of flags:

```
0x0001 ACC_PUBLIC
0x0040 ACC_BRIDGE
0x1000 ACC_SYNTHETIC
```

The meaning of these flags is

> - The ACC_BRIDGE flag is used to indicate a bridge method generated by a compiler for the Java programming language
> - The ACC_SYNTHETIC flag indicates that this method was generated by a compiler and does not appear in source code, unless it is one of the methods named in §4.7.8.

This combination is used by the Java Compiler if it needs to create "bridge methods": methods that are needed because of generics spezialisation / generics type erasure.

In your case you probably have:

```
public interface Entity<E> {}

public class SomeModel implements Entity<Long> {}

public interface QueryRepository<Id, E extends<Entity<Id>> {
    E get(Id id);
}

public class SomeModelQueryRepo implements QueryRepository<Long, SomeModel> {
    @Override
    public SomeModel get(Long id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For the class `SomeModelQueryRepo` to implement `QueryRepository` it **must** contain a method `Entity get(Object id)` because that is what the `QueryRepository` contains as method after type erasure.

The compiler therefore creates this synthetic bridge method:

```
    public Entity<Object> get(Object id) {
        return get((Long) id);
    }
```